# select recently incerted record from table in oracle 11g

Tags: oracle11g

- i have oracle 11g
- i have tables employee table and employee time data tables.
- and my table having id,employee_no,employee_in Time,...
- in one day i get with 1,100,17-JUN-14 04.57.19 PM,..., 2,100,17-JUN-14 05.57 PM...etc multiple records with multiple employe ids.
- how to get recently get recorded with using employee_no.
- i already tried with join of both tables and try to get employee name and employee_in Time
- please save my days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would really help to know the table structures and relevant columns in each. In addition it helps to know sample data and expected results and what you've tried to date.

Based on statement to " recently get recorded with using employee_no."  I take to mean get the most recent employee_in_time for each employee.

```
Select max(employee_In_Time), employee_no, trunc(employee_In_time) as CalDay
from employee_Time
Group by employee_no, trunc(employee_In_time)
```

This would return the most recent time entry for each employee, if you need other data from employee table a join should suffice. but without knowing results... not sure what you're after.

Comment: we are inserting employee records in time with employee no. recently in one day one employee 4 times entered in office i.e in time, then end of day i want to get last record of that employe in time value.(in another table having employee details- i am join this two two table getting employe name and no and in time details. need to get single record of last insertion record)

Comment: The above would return the max in time for an employee having multiple entries on the same day.  Is this what you're after?  It has no where clause so it's going to return this for each day, ever employee only their MAX intime for the day.

Comment: shouldn't need to max employee_no if it's in the group by.